# Disable temporarily scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm kind of new on JS. I have a script that detect the hash and change it according to the direction of scroll (basically: scroll down = #1, #2, #3...etc). But I want to add a delay between each scroll or between each hash change. I just can't figure it out how to do this.

Here's my code:

```
$(function (){
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(2);
    var length = $("section").length;
    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

    if (delta > 0 && hash == length)
        window.location.hash = "#s" + 1;
    else if (delta < 0 &&  hash == 1)
        window.location.hash = "#s" + length;
    else {
        if (delta > 0) {
            hash++;
            window.location.hash = "#s" + hash;
        }
        else {
            hash--;
                window.location.hash = "#s" + hash;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript setTimeout function to add a delay as below.

`setTimeout(function(){ your code; }, 3000);`

Comment: I heard about this function, but I don't know how to implement it on my script. If I just add my function between the bracket, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had a hard time implementing it since I'm not good in JS, but here's what I've done, it works really well;

```
$(window).on('wheel', scroll);
function scroll(e) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(2);
    var length = $("section").length;
    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

    if (delta > 0 && hash == length)
        window.location.hash = "#s" + 1;
    else if (delta < 0 && hash == 1)
        window.location.hash = "#s" + length;
    else {
        if (delta > 0) {
            hash++;
            window.location.hash = "#s" + hash;
        }
        else {
            hash--;
            window.location.hash = "#s" + hash;
        }
    }
    $(window).off('wheel', scroll);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(window).on('wheel', scroll);
    }, 1000);
    return false;
}
```